# How to enable -keystroke option of unclutter in unity?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, autohide

Recently I installed unclutter to hide the mouse pointer while I'm typing, since there is no option in Ubuntu 14.04 to hide mouse pointer. According to the man pages of unclutter ther is a option -keystroke that wait until a key has been pressed and hides the pointer. But my problem is that it doesn't work by running this command:

```
unclutter -keystroke &
```

Another hint in the man pages is that:

> LIMITATIONS:
>          The -keystroke option may not work (that is, the cursor will not disappear) with
>          clients that request KeyRelease events.  Games and Xt applications  using  KeyUp
>          in  their  translation  tables are most likely to suffer from this problem.  The
>          most feasible solution is to extend unclutter to use the XTest extension to  get
>          all keyboard and mouse events, though this of course requires XTest to be in the
>          server too.
>
> The -keystroke option does not distinguish modifier keys from keys  which  actu‐
>          ally  generate characters.  If desired this could be implemented in a simple way
>          by using XLookupString to see if any characters are returned.

I must tell that I wouldn't like a timer for hiding mouse when it's idle. I would like it work like the windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xbanish` to do this. It is well known that the `unclutter` keystroke function has been broken for quite some time. I have tested this solution and it works well.

First, install `git` if it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libxtst-dev x11proto-core-dev
```

Then, clone the repo and install `xbanish`:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/jcs/xbanish.git
cd xbanish
make
```

Now, set an `alias` for `xbanish`:

```
echo "alias xbanish='~/xbanish/xbanish &'" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

You can now run xbanish by simply running the following command:

```
xbanish
```

or

```
~/xbanish/xbanish &
```

---

Additionally, here's a helpful tip that has helped me so much when it comes to "no such file" errors.

You can use `apt-file search` to find out what package contains a file you are looking for. Here's an example: `apt-file search X11/X.h`

However, `apt-file` needs to be installed and you must run `sudo apt-file update` before you can use it:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run the make command. I also tried sudo make but the same error:

sajad@LoneWalker:~/xbanish$ make
cc -O2 -Wall -Wunused -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/X11R6/include -c xbanish.c -o xbanish.o
xbanish.c:35:19: fatal error: X11/X.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/X.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xbanish.o] Error 1

Comment: @sh2p Fortunately, this is quite easy to fix. It appears you are missing the file `/usr/include/X11/X.h`. Run the following commands to install `x11proto-core-dev`. Then, run: `sudo make clean` before you run `make`. Please post any more errors, thanks!

Comment: @sh2p Also, here's a helpful tip that has helped me so much when it comes to *no such file* errors. You can use `apt-file search` to find out what package contains a file you are looking for. Here's an example: `apt-file search X11/X.h`. However, `apt-file` needs to be installed and you must run `sudo apt-file update` before you can use it: `sudo apt-get install apt-file` and then run: `sudo apt-file update`

Comment: Thanks for your help @mchid
After installing 4 packages, and adding alias for xbanish it worked correctly. Please edit the first comment where u wrote x11proto-core-dev, it must be sudo apt-get install blah blah...
actually the second comment was more helpful and made my life easier!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had to install the libxtst-dev package to have Xfixes.h.